# GCM server direct from android app

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am creating a chat application on android using GCM. I'm already able do receive messages from the cloud and to send them manually through a PHP script using cURL. I can simple make an HTTPRequest to this script everytime a user send a message but I would like to know if there's a way to remove this script thus making the android app directly send the message to the cloud. If this is possible I also would like to know if it is the "right" way to do it or if the HTTPRequest is as good as it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. GCM is not meant to replace your entire infrastructure, just the push channel from your servers to the clients.

That said, there is this concept of Upstream Messaging (from device to Google's servers) but Google's servers then contact your servers (via XMPP of all things) to let you decide what to do next.

You cannot do device-to-device over GCM.